# Swift: dictionaries inside array

Tags: swift, swift-array, swift-dictionary

Data:

```
[
    { firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }
]
```

How can I have this kind of structure using swift array and dictionary? This data shows dictionaries inside an array, right? So I suggest:

```
var persons:Array = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

but this gives me the error:

```
Cannot convert the expressions type () to type Array<T>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Question: that error is for another line of code not included in your question, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
var persons = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var persons = [[String : String]]()
```

What your code does instead is to create an array filled in with an instance of `Dictionary<String, String>`, whereas I presume you want an empty instance of the array containing elements of `Dictionary<String, String>` type.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Xcode have you got?
Your code should work fine but the line:

```
var persons:Array = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

create the array with first empty dictionary, try this instead:

```
var persons:Array = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

var dic1 = ["Name" : "Jon"]
var dic2 = ["Surname" : "Smith"]

persons.append(dic1)
persons.append(dic2)

println(persons)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you really want a dictionary within an array? The code you've given indicates more an array with named columns, which can be achieved using something like the following:

```
struct Name {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
}

var persons1 : Array<Name> =  [
    Name(firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar"),
    Name(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
]
persons1[0].firstName       // "Foo"

var persons2 : Array<(firstName: String, lastName:String)> = [
    (firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Mean"),
    (firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar"),
    (firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
]

 persons2[1].firstName     // "Bar"
```

These are proper arrays and adressed as such using subscripts. The dictionary type is usually a combination of key and value, i.e. nickname as key, and name as value.

```
var nickNames : [String:String] =  [
    "mame" : "Mary Mean",
    "foba" : "Foo Bar",
    "jodo" : "John Doe"]

nickNames["mame"]!  // "Mary Mean"
```

And here we lookup on the key value, and get an optional value in return, which I forcefully unwrapped...

All of these can be appended rather easily, but do note that the named tuple variant, `persons2`, is not following recommended practice. Also note that the Array of Dictionaries allow for inclusion on different keys as suggested in my last injection.

```
persons1.append( Name(firstName: "Some", lastName: "Guy") )
persons2.append( firstName: "Another", lastName: "Girl" )

nickNames["anna"] = "Ann Nabel"

// Array of Dictionaries
var persons : [[String:String]] = [
    [ "firstName" : "Firstly", "lastName" : "Lastly"],
    [ "firstName" : "Donald", "lastName" : "Duck"]
]

persons.append( ["firstName" : "Georg", "middleName" : "Friedrich", "lastName" : "Händel"] )
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this can work for you:

```
var persons: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = Array()
```

and now you can add the names:

```
persons.append(["firstName": "Foo", "lastName": "Bar"]);
persons.append(["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doo"]);
```

---

*NOTE: if you are insecure how to use literals, just don't use them*.