# Swift: array of dictionaries has count of 1 after initialization but should have 0

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6.1, swift-array, swift-dictionary

```
var persons = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
println(persons.count)
```

prints `1`. I see that there is an empty dictionary inside the array when it is initialized but is there a way to avoid that and having 0 elements instead of 1? Later I need to be able to do:

```
persons.append(["firstName": "Foo", "lastName": "Bar"])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wasn't that answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26735091/1187415 in reply to your previous question? Did you copy the suggested code correctly?

Comment: @MartinR your right, but as I wrote this question I thought it is a different problem. We may close this.

Comment: I feel guilty... it's me who answered to the other question, and I should have noticed that, considering that the answer is pretty much the same. @MartinR, do you think I should delete my answer here?

Comment: @Antonio no totally fine, you don't have to delete it.

Comment: @Antonio: You can't delete the answer anymore because it has been accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using this:

```
[Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

you are creating an array with one element `Dictionary<String, String>()`

The correct way is to move the parenthesis after the square brackets:

```
[Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

That declares an array of type `Dictionary<String, String>`, and instantiate it.

Equivalent way of creating it is:

```
Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place brackets outside:

```
var persons = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be

```
var persons = Dictionary<String, String>()
println(persons.count)
```

or

```
var persons = [String : String]()
println(persons.count)
```

but not both syntaxes at the same time?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html